# Laravel "Many To Many Polymorphic Relations" returning empty array

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5.3

**Album.php**

```
/**
 * Get all of the orders for the album.
 *
 * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\MorphToMany
 */
public function orders()
{
    return $this->morphToMany(Order::class, 'orderable');
}
```

**Book.php**

```
/**
 * Get all of the orders for the book.
 *
 * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\MorphToMany
 */
public function orders()
{
    return $this->morphToMany(Order::class, 'orderable');
}
```

**Order.php**

```
/**
 * Get all of the albums that are assigned this order.
 *
 * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\MorphToMany
 */
public function albums()
{
    return $this->morphedByMany(Album::class, 'orderable');
}

/**
 * Get all of the books that are assigned this order.
 *
 * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\MorphToMany
 */
public function books()
{
    return $this->morphedByMany(Book::class, 'orderable');
}
```

**Orderables Table:**

- order_id
- orderable_id
- orderable_type

I've created some records in books, albums, orders, and orderables. But when I'm trying to get books from order it returns me an empty array. There is no error, only empty array. Do you have any idea what problem could be?

Comment: Show code, where you get books!

Comment: Please include all the relevant code, including where you're using the relationship.

Comment: https://gist.github.com/zgabievi/c1091f9975d14b13dc1ce5f0cde27800 I think this gist will be helpful

Comment: In your model you're listing the class as `Book::class` and in the table it's showing `App\Book` -- is the book model in your app folder? Or somewhere else?